# How to use ProgressBar instead of deprecated ProgressDialog in BaseActivity?

Tags: android, progressdialog, android-progressbar

Since the [ProgressDialog](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog) has been deprecated in API level 26, how can we use [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) instead? In particular, how can we do it in a way that can be shared across all activities/fragments?

Example usage of ProgressDialog in BaseActivity:

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;

@Override
public void showLoading() {
    //...
}

@Override
public void hideLoading() {
    //..
}
```

Now this is a very clean solution because ProgressDialog is not a widget, and does not need to be a part of any view xml. Since ProgressBar has to be declared in one of the xml files, how to use it in the same way as ProgressDialog here?

I'm using a `NavigationDrawer` with a corresponding `Activity`, and I swap `Fragment`s to provide content.

Comment: you have 2 options, either go for a custom dialog with a progress bar on it. or just integrate the progress bar directly into your layout. choose whichever option is more appropriate for your use case.

Comment: it's a shift away from modal pop-ups which hangs your whole app while a task is in progress... android recommends doing away with such modal dialogs -and just show a simple progressbar, so that users can continue to use the rest of the app while your background service runs.

Comment: So your suggestion is to integrate ProgressBar inside of DrawerActivity layout? This is what I though of, but does not provide the best solution, for example if I wanted to add some other activities, I would not cover everything like in BaseActivity... I think I will go with custom Dialog then, thanks anyways @SagarNayak

Answer (score -2):

Activity

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ProgressBar progressBar;

    public void showLoading() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.Visible);
    }

    public void hideLoading() {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.Gone);
    }
}
```

Fragment

```
((BaseActivity) getContext).showLoading();
```

Now that's the easy and unsafe way to do it.

Antoher way of doing it is to implement this into your activites. Put a progresbar in the xml.

```
public interface OnProgressChanged {
    void show();
    void hide();
}
```

then on each fragment

```
OnProgressChanged onProgressChangedListener;

@override
onAttach(Context context) {
    Activity activity = null;

    if (context instanceof Activity){
        activity = (Activity) context;
    }

    try {
        onProgressChangedListener = (OnProgressChanged) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString() + " must implement OnProgressChanged");
    } catch(NullPointerException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException("Error: onAttach(Context context) -> context not instance of Activity");
    }
}


// somewhere else in the code
onProgressChangedListener.show();
```

There is many ways to do what you want. I'd look into MVP pattern if I was you.

Comment: You mean `((BaseActivity) getActivity()).showLoading()` for fragments and just `showLoading()` for Activities, but what if the `getActivity()` returns null? :)

Comment: Null check it, it's pretty obvious?